# differentiate Hybrid App or web app

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, hybrid

I am writing a hybrid app for Android/IOS, with rendering on web-kit, I want to use the same views (HTML5) for my mobile web app.

Is there a way to identify through jQuery or plain javascript, whether the loaded thing is an Hybrid App or Mobile web, so that I can conditional show hide components for Mobile web and Hybrid app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, nowadays we can write our mobile apps (hybrid) using HTML, CSS and JS. And wrap it in a wrapper (android/ios), sometimes using [Phonegap](http://build.phonegap.com/).

You approach looks good but lets try another approach. why do not you set some kind of flag in your codebase that will help you to figure out whether your app is running inside webview or in the browser itself?

Hope this would help.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy, but I wanted to know do we have something in api's to have that.

Comment: I have not come across such thing yet but I've used https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins before to access the phone's native functinalities from javascript.

Comment: Hey @sij, just recalled that when you make an hybrid app, the html files loaded into a webview has `file:///` protocol and for a hosted application it is `http` or `https`. So you can check whether `window.location.href.indexOf('http') === 0 ? 'web' : 'hybrid'`

Answer (score 0):

I use this snippet that works for me

```
function isApp() {

var app = document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1 && document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1;
  if (app) {
      // PhoneGap application
      //alert("U're using cordova");
      return true;
  } else {
      //alert("U're using browser");
      return false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you. Regards.